# Replace value in data frame with value from other data frame based on set of conditions

Tags: r

In df1 I need to replace values for msec with corresponding values in df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('rs', 'rs', 'rs', 'tr','tr','tr'), cond=c(1,1,2,1,1,2), 
block=c(2,2,4,2,2,4), correct=c(1,0,1,1,1,0), msec=c(456,678,756,654,625,645))

df2 <- data.frame(ID=c('rs', 'rs', 'tr','tr'), cond=c(1,2,1,2), 
block=c(2,4,2,4), mean=c(545,664,703,765))
```

In df1, if `correct==0`, then reference `df2` with the matching values of `ID`, `cond`, and `block`. Replace the value for `msec` in `df1` with the corresponding value for `mean` in `df2`.

For example, the second row in df1 has `correct==0`. So, in `df2` find the corresponding row where `ID=='rs'`, `cond==1`, `block==2` and use the value for mean (`mean=545`) to replace the value for msec (`msec=678`). Note that in df1 combinations of ID, block, and cond can repeat, but each combination occurs only once in df2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `data.table` package:

```
# load the 'data.table' package
library(data.table)

# convert the data.frame's to data.table's
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# update df1 by reference with a join with df2
df1[df2[, correct := 0], on = .(ID, cond, block, correct), msec := i.mean]
```

which gives:

```
> df1
   ID cond block correct msec
1: rs    1     2       1  456
2: rs    1     2       0  545
3: rs    2     4       1  756
4: tr    1     2       1  654
5: tr    1     2       1  625
6: tr    2     4       0  765
```

Note: The above code will update `df1` instead of creating a new dataframe, which is more memory-efficient.

Comment: `df1[c(list(correct = 0), df2), on=.(correct, ID, cond, block), msec := i.mean ]` ? I guess it's pretty much the same. Also maybe worth mentioning that this updates df1 instead of making a new table (like the dplyr variant).

Comment: This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use base R with an `interaction()` and a `match()`. How about:

```
df1[which(df1$correct==0),"msec"] <- df2[match(interaction(df1[which(df1$correct==0),c("ID","cond","block")]), 
                                               interaction(df2[,c("ID","cond", "block")])),
                                         "mean"]

df1
#        ID cond block correct msec
#1 rs    1     2       1  456
#2 rs    1     2       0  545
#3 rs    2     4       1  756
#4 tr    1     2       1  654
#5 tr    1     2       1  625
#6 tr    2     4       0  765
```

We overwrite the `correct == 0` columns with their matched rows in `df2$mean`

**Edit:** Another option would be a sql merge this could look like:

```
library(sqldf)
merged <- sqldf('SELECT l.ID, l.cond, l.block, l.correct,
                        case when l.correct == 0 then r.mean else l.msec end as msec
                FROM df1 as l
                LEFT JOIN df2 as r
                ON l.ID = r.ID AND l.cond = r.cond AND l.block = r.block')


merged
  ID cond block correct msec
1 rs    1     2       1  456
2 rs    1     2       0  545
3 rs    2     4       1  756
4 tr    1     2       1  654
5 tr    1     2       1  625
6 tr    2     4       0  765
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`. This solution `left_join` all columns and `mutate` when correct is 0.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,df2)%>%
mutate(msec=ifelse(correct==0,mean,msec))%>%
select(-mean)

  ID cond block correct msec
1 rs    1     2       1  456
2 rs    1     2       0  545
3 rs    2     4       1  756
4 tr    1     2       1  654
5 tr    1     2       1  625
6 tr    2     4       0  765
```