# How to access column values of a TSV based on computationally read out keywords in Python/Pandas/R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I am going to describe my question with this minimal, reproducible example (reprex). I have two tab separated value files `df1.map` and `df2.map`. `df1.map` looks like this:

```
1       BICF2G630707759 0       3014448
1       BICF2S2358127   0       3068620
1       BICF2P1173580   0       3079928
1       BICF2G630707846 0       3082514
1       BICF2G630707893 0       3176980
1       TIGRP2P175_RS8671583    0       3198886
1       BICF2P1383091   0       3212349
1       TIGRP2P259_RS8993730    0       3249189
1       BICF2P186608    0       3265742
1       BICF2G630707908 0       3273096
```

`df2.map` is this:

```
1       BICF2P413765    0       85620576
1       BICF2P413768    0       85621395
1       BICF2P860004    0       85633349
1       BICF2G630707846   0       85660017
1       BICF2G630707893     0       85684560
1       CHR1_85660017   0       85660017
1       BICF2P91636     0       85684560
1       CHR1_85685260   0       85685260
1       BICF2P172347    0       85700399
1       BICF2P1125163   0       85707031
```

The second column in each file holds an ID information. The question is: Check for every ID in `df1.map` if it is present in `df2.map`. If it is present, take the information of that ID, of that row from the columns 1 and 4 from `df2.map` and over-write the columns 1 and 4 in `df1.map` with the information from `df2.map`.

I tried one solution with python (after converting from TSV to CSV):

```
import pandas as pd

CF2 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', low_memory=False)
CF3 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', low_memory=False)

i = 0
while i < CF2.shape[0]:
    if (CF2[CF2.columns[1]].values[i]) == (CF3[CF3.columns[1]]):
        print (CF3[CF3.columns[0]])
i = i + 1
```

Yet, that resulted only in errors.

Then I tried to solve it in R:

```
CFTwo <- read.table("df1.map", sep="\t", header=FALSE)
CFThree <- read.table("df2.map", sep="\t", header=FALSE)

for (i in CFThree [,2]) {
    if (i == CFTwo [,2]) {
        print(CFTwo [,c(1,2,4)])}}
```

That gave 50 warnings and no result.
Since I was already not able to get the right values printed, I am far away from over-writing and changing files.
Besides Python and R I am also open to a solution in bash.

Comment: You could use a left join with [tag:r]'s [tag:data.table] package, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34598139/2204410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32884254/2204410) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43545307/2204410) for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this problem by merging the second file with the first one, and checking for `NA` values to recode `V1` and `V4` with `if_else()`. A `dplyr` based solution looks like this:

```
file1 <- "1       BICF2G630707759 0       3014448
1       BICF2S2358127   0       3068620
1       BICF2P1173580   0       3079928
1       BICF2G630707846 0       3082514
1       BICF2G630707893 0       3176980
1       TIGRP2P175_RS8671583    0       3198886
1       BICF2P1383091   0       3212349
1       TIGRP2P259_RS8993730    0       3249189
1       BICF2P186608    0       3265742
1       BICF2G630707908 0       3273096"

file2 <- "1       BICF2P413765    0       85620576
1       BICF2P413768    0       85621395
1       BICF2P860004    0       85633349
1       BICF2G630707846   0       85660017
1       BICF2G630707893     0       85684560
1       CHR1_85660017   0       85660017
1       BICF2P91636     0       85684560
1       CHR1_85685260   0       85685260
1       BICF2P172347    0       85700399
1       BICF2P1125163   0       85707031"
```

We read the raw data, and for the first file use the default column names. For the second file, we change the names of every column except the key that joins with the first file. This avoids a duplicate column names problem when we join the files.

```
df1.map <- read.table(text=file1,header=FALSE)
df2.map <- read.table(text = file2,header = FALSE,
                      col.names = c("df2.V1","V2","df2.V3","df2.V4"))
```

Next, we join the data and use `mutate()` to set the values of `V1` and `V4` if the corresponding values of `df2.V1` and `df2.V4` are not `NA`. We use `left_join()` because the output data should include all rows from `df1.map`, regardless of whether `df2.map` contributed data to a particular row.

Once recoded, we drop the columns that begin with `df2.*` from the result data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
df1.map %>% left_join(.,df2.map) %>%
     mutate(V1 = if_else(is.na(df2.V1),V1,df2.V1),
            V4 = if_else(is.na(df2.V4),V4,df2.V4)) %>%
     select(.,-c(df2.V1,df2.V3,df2.V4))
```

...and the output:

```
Joining, by = "V2"
   V1                   V2 V3       V4
1   1      BICF2G630707759  0  3014448
2   1        BICF2S2358127  0  3068620
3   1        BICF2P1173580  0  3079928
4   1      BICF2G630707846  0 85660017
5   1      BICF2G630707893  0 85684560
6   1 TIGRP2P175_RS8671583  0  3198886
7   1        BICF2P1383091  0  3212349
8   1 TIGRP2P259_RS8993730  0  3249189
9   1         BICF2P186608  0  3265742
10  1      BICF2G630707908  0  3273096
>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which worked here for the reprex and also for my actual bigger dataset - thanks!